# How can I get the _registryAlias from Entity

Tags: cakephp-3.0

Let say I have:

$user = $this->Users->newEntity();
So now how can I get the text 'Users' from the $user entity?

In the Entity class I see the _registryAlias, but it is protected and don't have any function to get that. (I dont want to modify the core also)

I need this for my global function that I want to pass only the $user (not to pass both $user and 'Users' to that function).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look closely there *is* a method that returns that properties value: `EntityTrait::source()`

See **[API > \Cake\Datasource\EntityTrait::source()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.Datasource.EntityTrait.html#_source)**

> [...]
>   If called with no arguments, it returns the alias of the repository this entity came from if it is known.
>   [...]

Comment: Thanks. This is what i want :) .